# How to restore starting position after dragging using WinRTBehaviours?

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime

I have an image which drag using WinRTBehaviours.I want to restore it to starting position if the target position is not desired.While I am setting the starting position using canvas properties it shows in another position.Any help will really appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Just save possition in varible OnLoad event?
Then set possition from varible.

Answer (score 0):

WinRTBehaviors doesn't include actual functional behaviors. If you mean [DragFlickBehavior from Win8nl](http://win8nl.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/21543#274325) then it doesn't seem to support it, though you could easily add that support - just handle ManipulationStarting and ManipulationCompleted events.